# How to sum up only positive or only negative integers the user inputs and how to calculate the avg

Tags: c++

I have to figure out how to calculate the sum of negative integers and their avg. Sum of positive integers and the avg. And the sum of all numbers and the avg. I have gotten the last part already but how do I calculate the sum of negative integers and avg, and positive integers and avg using a while loop?

I provided my code below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
       
        int x;
        double avg = 0.0;
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        
    // ask users for input
        cout << ("Welcome to the greatest calculator!\n");
        cout << ("Please enter 10 integers seperated by spaces \n");
        
        do {
            std::cin >> x;
            sum = sum + x;
            count = count + 1;
        }
        while (count < 10);
        
        // calculate average
    
         avg = sum/10.0;
        
        // output average
        cout << fixed;
        cout << "For all 10 numbers the sum is " << sum << "." "The average is " << setprecision (2) << sum/10.0 <<".\n";
        return 0;
        
    }
```

The output should look something like this.

```
Please enter 10 integers separated by spaces:
1 -1 45 17 28 -2 0 9 -14 11

Upon our intelligent calculations, here is the result:
+ There are 7 positive numbers, sum = 111.00 and average = 15.86
+ There are 3 negative numbers, sum = -17.00 and average = -5.67
+ For all 10 numbers, sum = 94.00 and average = 9.40 */
```

Comment: `int count = 0;` Add two more variables `int countPositive = 0, countNegative = 0;` and do the same for `sum`. Then update them inside the same loop, depending on the sign of `x`.

Comment: But at the sign of the `prancing_pony` keep an eye out for `strider`.

Comment: If I handed you a pencil and paper, and on that paper was a column of both positive and negative values, how would you solve this on paper? Once you figure that out, implementing it in your code should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use two variable int negativeVar=0 , PositiveVar=0 . In the loop try a condition if(GivenNumber<0) to detect the given number is negative or positive. Then add all positive and negative value separately and make avarage.
(Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this (notice comments):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
  // Declaration and initialization of the required variables
  float cPositive = 0.0f;
  float cNegative = 0.0f;
  int it = 0;

  std::cout << "Enter 10 numbers (floating point assignable): \n";

  // Looping till 10 iterations
  do {
    float temp;
    std::cin >> temp;

    // If the number is greater than zero, i.e. (+ve) then cPositive sums up
    // otherwise, cNegative
    if (temp > 0) cPositive += temp;
    else if (temp <= 0.0f) cNegative -= temp;

  } while (++it < 10); // Increment and comparison together

  // Final results
  std::cout \
    << "Sum of positive: " << cPositive << std::endl
    << "Sum of negative: -" << cNegative << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**A simple test case:**

```
Enter 10 numbers (floating point assignable): 
10.5
-1.5
2.2
5.5
-3.8
-99.3
10
4.5
-1.0
0
Sum of positive: 32.7
Sum of negative: -105.6
```

Moreover, if you want to see average, then declare two variables, `pos` and `neg` where both are initially zero. After that, when a positive number or negative number occurs, just increment `pos` or `neg` and divide with them by `cPositive` or `cNegative` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

// lets declare some variable first.
  int positiveSum =0;  //this will hold sum of positive nums
int negativeSum =0; // this will hold sum of negative nums
int totalSum =0; // this will hold sum of all the nums

int number=0; // user input for number
for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++)  // loop from 1 to 10 times
{
    cout << " Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    
    // now check if number is positive or negative
    if (number >=0)
    {
        positiveSum += number;    // adds this number to positiveSum
    }
    else if (number < 0)
   {
       negativeSum += number;   // adds this number to negativeSum
   }

} 

// So finally add the positiveSum and negativeSum to get the totalSum
totalSum = positiveSum + negativeSum;

cout << endl;
cout << " Total of Positive numbers is: " << positiveSum << endl;
cout << " Total of Negative numbers is: " << negativeSum << endl;
cout << " Total of all numbers is: " << totalSum << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below produces the following output:

```
$ ./main 
The (sum, avg) of negative integers = (-15, -5)
The (sum, avg) of positive integers = (6, 2)
The (sum, avg) of all numbers = (-9, -1.5)
```

Please read the comments because they are in fact the detailed answer.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // For convenience, keep the numbers in an std::array. std::vector is
    // equally convenient.
    std::array<int, 6> integers { 1, -4, 2, -5, 3, -6 };

    // Define variables that store the sums and the counts.
    int positiveSum = 0;
    int positiveCnt = 0;
    int negativeSum = 0;
    int negativeCnt = 0;

    // Iterate over the numbers taking one of them at a time.
    int i = 0;
    while (i < integers.size())
    {
        int number = integers[i];

        // Is the number positive?...
        if (number >= 0)
        {
            // ... it is - add it to the positive sum and increment the count.
            positiveSum += number;
            ++positiveCnt;
        }
        // The number is not positive, so it must be negative...
        else
        {
            // ... add it to the negative sum and increment the count.
            negativeSum += number;
            ++negativeCnt;
        }
       
        // Get ready for the next number.
        ++i;
    }

    // Time to print out the results.
    // Note that before we calculate the average, we have to cast at least one
    // of the terms of the division to floating point type. Otherwise the
    // division will be done with integers where the result is also an integer
    // (e.g. 3 / 2 -> 1).
    // Only affter the casting you will be getting expected answers
    // (e.g. double(3) / 2 -> 1.5).
    std::cout << 
        "The (sum, avg) of negative integers = (" << 
        negativeSum << ", " << 
        double(negativeSum) / negativeCnt << ")" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << 
        "The (sum, avg) of positive integers = (" << 
        positiveSum << ", " << 
        double(positiveSum) / positiveCnt << ")" << std::endl;

    std::cout << 
        "The (sum, avg) of all numbers = (" << 
        negativeSum + positiveSum << ", " << 
        double(negativeSum + positiveSum) / (negativeCnt + positiveCnt) << ")" << std::endl;
}
```